# Web API routing not recognizing verb in Action's name

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am trying to POST to this controller Action:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostRegister(JObject data)
```

When I call this from an html page it returns a 404 error, however if I change it to:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(JObject data)
```

the call is properly routed.  I know if I create a Web Api project from VS it works, but I am building this project from an Empty Web Project template.  It doesn't seem to be picking up the verb hints in the action name.

below is the routing config:

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "AdminApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/admin/{action}/"
        );
    }
```

jquery call:

```
$.post("api/account/admin/register/", { name: "Me", password: "test" });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have added `{action}` as a route parameter (and not an optional one), you now need to supply that route parameter for every call, i.e. always supply an action. And it must **match** the ActionMethod name.  Http verb hints are still applied for the allowed actions (e.g. I couldn't `GET api/account/admin/postregister/`).

There are a few options open to you to fix/change. You could override the action name :

```
[ActionName("Register")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostRegister(JObject data)
```

Or you could call it register and only allow posts using aatribute

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(JObject data)
```

Or you could go for a more 'RESTful' style of routing. e.g create a registrations controller and simply have a POST method to create a registraion.